# How to use Cache.Insert?

Tags: c#, sql

Well, im pretty new in C#, but now im trying to use cache.insert to see the performance of a SQL query with SqlCache Class. So my question is where do i obtain the value to use cache.insert(key, value, dependency)?

Comment: Which value?  The key, value or dependency?  key is what ever you want to call it.  value is the result set (maybe convert to JSON or something).  Dependency, probably not required.

Comment: Cache.insert use IIS cache instead of SQL cache, you can cache data in server memory using key and any type of value, i.e. Dataset or datatable, with the properties with how long and refresh or expired after a fixed interval of time.

See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.caching.cache.insert?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was very confuse with the values that i need to use for cache.insert